# Xaml controls don't show up

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with FreshMvvm. Some of its users experience a problem on their iPhones. A page comes up empty. Here is how the page would look with a simulated exception:

[image]

All static xaml stuff is there, including labels. But our customers see this instead:

[image]

In the ScrollView, only the BoxViews with height = 1 that make those horizontal lines, are there. And no labels.

Here is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"


x:Class="LATICRETE_MobileApp.Pages.CoverageCalculator.CoverageCalculatorResultsPage"
ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:LATICRETE_MobileApp.Controls"
Title="Coverage Results" >
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="0">
            <StackLayout Margin="30">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="22" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Tile Size:"      FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Label Text="Tile Thickness:" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Label Text="Joint Size:"     FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Label Text="Trowel Size:"    FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" />

                    <Label Text="{Binding TileSize}"      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray"     Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding TileThickness}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray"     Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding JointSize}"     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray"     Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding TrowelSize}"    Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LaticreteColor}" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                </Grid>

                <Label Text="{Binding Adhesive}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Text="{Binding AdhesiveCoverage}" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Grout}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Text="{Binding GroutCoverage}" />
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="1" />

                <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelParagraphStyle}" Text="*Calculated coverage indicated is approximate, based on nominal tile size and is provided for purposes of estimation only." />
                <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelParagraphStyle}" Text="Actual grout coverage will vary depending on jobsite conditions, actual tile size and installed grout joint size. Use of sufficient thin-set reduces grout requirement." />
                <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelParagraphStyle}" Text="Add 10% to coverage estimates for waste, spillage and clean-up. Add 10%-15% to grout coverage estimate when grouting unglazed quarry tile." />

                <Button 
                Text="{Binding ButtonShareText}"
                Command="{Binding ShareCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <controls:Toolbar 
            ButtonCalculatorIcon="{Binding ButtonCalculatorIcon}" 
            ButtonDistributorLocatorIcon="{Binding ButtonDistributorLocatorIcon}" 
            ButtonScanQRCodeIcon="{Binding ButtonScanQRCodeIcon}" 
            ButtonVideoCallIcon="{Binding ButtonVideoCallIcon}" 
            ButtonMoreIcon="{Binding ButtonMoreIcon}" 
            CalculatorCommand="{Binding CalculatorCommand}"
            DistributorsLocatorCommand="{Binding DistributorsLocatorCommand}"
            ScanQRCommand="{Binding ScanQRCommand}"
            VideoCallCommand="{Binding VideoCallCommand}"
            MoreFeaturesCommand="{Binding MoreFeaturesCommand}"    
            ShowVideoChat="{Binding ShowVideoChat}"             
            ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ToolbarTemplate}" 
            Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>    

</ContentPage.Content>
```

On App Center Diagnostics, I could see exceptions like this:

[image]

I don't know if this causes our issue, but that is the only thing I could find.

Also, on the same iPhone models some users have this issue, and others don't. I personally could not reproduce it on my phones.

ADDED:

The code-behind constructor and the pagemodel constructor contain almost nothing:

```
    public CoverageCalculatorResultsPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
```

...

```
    public CoverageCalculatorResultsPageModel()
    {
        ScreenName = "Coverage Results";

        ShareCommand = new Command(async () => await Share());
    }
```

Pagemodel's Init():

```
    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Init(initData);

            throw new Exception("Test Exception: remove when done");

            _previousModel = (CoverageCalculatorPageModel)initData;

            // Standard units
            string lengthUnits = "\"";
            string coverageUnits = " Ft²";

            double tileWidth = Convert.ToDouble(_previousModel.TileWidth, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double tileHeight = Convert.ToDouble(_previousModel.TileHeight, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double jointWidth = Convert.ToDouble(_previousModel.SelectedJointSize.Key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double tileThickness = Convert.ToDouble(_previousModel.SelectedTileThickness.Key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (_previousModel.SelectedUnit.Code == UnitCode.Metric)
            {
                lengthUnits = "mm";
                coverageUnits = "M²";

                // Convert to standard units
                tileWidth /= 25.4;
                tileHeight /= 25.4;
            }

            // Perform adhesive calculation
            // Official formula is: Coverage (Sq Ft)/Unit = (coverage_cuInPerUnit/((Trowel_Height * 0.707108)/2)) * 0.0069444
            double cuInPerUnit = _previousModel.SelectedAdhesive.Coverage;
            double trowelHeight = Convert.ToDouble(_previousModel.SelectedTrowelSize.Key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double adhesiveCoverage = (cuInPerUnit / ((trowelHeight * 0.559) / 2)) * 0.0069444;

            // Perform grout calculation
            // Official formula is: Coverage (Sq Ft)/Unit = coverage_cuInPerUnit/((Tile_Width+Tile_Height+Joint_Width)*Tile_Thickness*Joint_Width*(144/((Tile_Width+Joint_Width)*(Tile_Height+Joint_Width))))
            cuInPerUnit = _previousModel.SelectedGrout.Coverage;
            double groutCoverage = cuInPerUnit / ((tileWidth + tileHeight + jointWidth) * tileThickness * jointWidth * (144 / ((tileWidth + jointWidth) * (tileHeight + jointWidth))));

            if (_previousModel.SelectedUnit.Code == UnitCode.Metric)
            {
                // Convert coverages to metric units if necessary (sqft to m2)
                adhesiveCoverage *= 0.092903;
                groutCoverage *= 0.092903;
            }

            TileSize = $"{_previousModel.TileWidth}{lengthUnits} x {_previousModel.TileHeight}{lengthUnits}";
            TileThickness = _previousModel.SelectedTileThickness.Value;
            JointSize = _previousModel.SelectedJointSize.Value;
            TrowelSize = _previousModel.SelectedTrowelSize.Value;
            Adhesive = _previousModel.SelectedAdhesive.Name;
            AdhesiveCoverage = $"Adhesive Coverage per Unit*: {adhesiveCoverage: #.##}{coverageUnits}";
            Grout = _previousModel.SelectedGrout.Name;
            GroutCoverage = $"Grout Coverage per Unit*: {groutCoverage: #.##}{coverageUnits}";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex, true);
        }
    }
```

All the data is obtained from the user on the previous page or from the calculations shown above.

Comment: If there was something wrong with your xaml, it would happen on all devices. A problem that happens on only some devices indicates a timing problem. A problem that causes some UI to appear, but not others, has one of two causes: 1) A binding problem, or 2) an exception that happens part way through the page rendering ...

Comment: ... Add to question: 1) the constructor in the page's code behind. 2) the constructor of your view model. 3) The method(s) that prepare any bound variables. (Variables in VM that are referred to using `{Binding ...}`.) 4) To prepare the data, are you querying a web server, or local files? Show code related to that. 5) My best guess: you'll need to make some change in the order in which you do things. Possibly also wrap some code in `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` or similar. 6) `x:Name="topLayout"` on `ScrollView`, then after prepping all data, in code behind: `topLayout.ForceLayout();`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I added the information you requested.

Comment: Looks good. And even if there was a problem in that code, it wouldn't explain why none of the static xaml text appears. As your test confirms. Try wrapping the entire contents of `Init` method inside `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. EXCEPT `base.Init(initData);` shouldn't be inside that, so move that line to start of method. Actually I'm not 100% sure BeginInvoke is a good idea in this case. Depends when FreshMVVM calls that Init.

Comment: Is there any other code running in the background, when this page is about to appear? Communication with server perhaps? IOS version - is it a particular version of iOS on the phones that don't work, versus those that do? So far, the symptom doesn't make sense to me. If you are in contact with one of those users, ask them to RESTART (power off, then back on) their phone. And uninstall, reinstall the app.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve They did all this, and nothing helped. It is not a particular version. E.g. it happened on X and 13, though on my 13 it does not happen.  I am not sure if anything is running on the background. I guess, it should not. You said you are not sure about BeginInvoke. So should I try that? I am asking before trying it, as it is some process...

Comment: **1)** *"it happened on X and 13"* Those are not `iOS versions`. On phone, see `Settings > General > About > Software Version`. It its up-to-date, it will be `15.6`, or the just released `15.6.1`. I was wondering if people are running an older iOS version. Should not matter - just trying to find some common factor. **2)** Try `BeginInvoke` on *your* device. If it seems okay, then its something to try, if no one comes up with any better idea.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve With BeginInvokeOnMainThread only static xaml shows up, but no data.